# Mobile Safari / iPhone - Orientation of 180° not recognized

Tags: iphone, safari, screen-orientation

Mobile Safari doesn't seem to recognize an orientation of 180° on the iPhone.

If I change the orientation from 0° to 90° to 180° the view remains in landscape mode. Also no orientation change event is fired on an orientation value of 180.

Is this a known bug? If so, is there a workaround?

Please be aware that I'm using the iOS Simulator. An iPhone is not at my disposal.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug, it's a feature! :)

Looks like Mobile Safari on iPhone doesn't support an upside-down portrait view. I say "looks like", because I didn't find any official statement regarding the supported orientations, but several inofficial ones, e.g. in Nicholas C. Zakas' book [Professional JavaScript for Web Developers](http://books.google.de/books?id=KW9G9rdlStIC&pg=PA418#v=onepage&q&f=false) (Page 418, Paragraph 1).

Answer (score 1):

Apple's Human Interface Guidelines imply that is is possible, just not on certain devices.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/

> An app that runs only in portrait mode should rotate its content 180
>   degrees when the device rotates 180 degrees — except on iPhone X,
>   which doesn’t support upside-down portrait mode.

Their documentation on `supportedInterfaceOrientations` tells a similar story.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621435-supportedinterfaceorientations

> For example, the UIInterfaceOrientation.portraitUpsideDown orientation
>   is not supported on iPhone X.

Also see:

[App rotates to landscape and portrait, but won't rotate upside down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58328275/app-rotates-to-landscape-and-portrait-but-wont-rotate-upside-down)

[Cannot rotate interface orientation to portrait upside down on iPhone X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46580472/cannot-rotate-interface-orientation-to-portrait-upside-down-on-iphone-x)