# Cannot rotate interface orientation to portrait upside down on iPhone X

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode9, iphone-x

We have an app which makes use of an accessory connected to the audio jack(or lightning port in iPhone7 or later).It needs to be run in certain orientations, depending on iOS device.

There are currently no issues setting device orientation in either simulator or actual device for any iPhone, except the iPhoneX simulator.

Current code for setting orientation:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    //device checks omitted
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

[Target settings with orientations enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beq84.png)

Stack trace:

```
TF uncaught exception reason : Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [RootNavigationController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES
2017-10-05 09:35:02.692945+0200 [65045:74145368] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [RootNavigationController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'
```

This is  working on iPhone5, iPhone6, iPhone6+, iPhone7 and iPhone7+ devices and iPhone8 simulators. It doesn't seem to be an iOS11 issue either as my iPhone7 is currently running iOS11. The only device I'm currently having issues with is the iPhoneX simulator.

Comment: On iOS 11.2 shouldAutorotate is not called any more. All old rotation code seems to be deprecated: "As of iOS 8, all rotation-related methods are deprecated" in the documentation for UIViewController. I'm having a hard time with this too trying to prevent rotation on iPhone X.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that the iPhone X will not support upside-down orientation; see https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/268015. An Apple staffer says, "It is by design.  We're getting documentation updated in a future release to reflect that."

You still get the orientation change notification, at least in the sim, but as you found, Bad Things may happen if you act on it. In my case I don't get an exception, but my UI doesn't redraw properly.

I'm adding code to detect an upside-down iPhone X and prevent the UI redraw; it works in the sim, and we'll have to wait and see if it'll work on the real device (fortunately my use case for upside-down only involves a headphone-jack device, so loss of upside-down on iPhone X isn't a big deal for me).

The upshot is that those of us using lighting port Sensors That Want To Be On Top will not be able to offer iPhone X users the same usability as on "lesser" iPhones, at least not without some seriously tedious UI jiggery-pokery involving lots of affine transforms to rotate and/or flip elements to *appear* upside-down while still conforming to what the phone thinks *it's* doing. Sigh.

Comment: I guess Apple was too lazy to come up with a meaningful way to adapt the layout of the **split** status bar of the iPhone X to be displayed on the notchless, bottom edge of the screen.

Comment: Too much even for Apple I guess! `View.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins (iOS8+), layoutMarginsDidChange(iOS8+), VC.layoutMargins(dep.)→View.directionalLayoutMargins(iOS11), VC.viewLayoutMarginsDidChange(iOS11), VC.systemMinimumLayoutMargins(iOS11), VC.viewRespectsSystemMinimumLayoutMargins(iOS11), View.safeAreaInsets(iOS11), insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea(iOS11), VC.viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange (iOS11), View.safeAreaLayoutGuide(iOS11)` **VC.additionalSafeAreaInsets(iOS11) - I give, no iPhoneX upside-down!**

Comment: Seems this "feature" has made its way into the HIG: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/ ...An app that runs only in portrait mode should rotate its content 180 degrees when the user rotates the device 180 degrees— **except on iPhone X**, which doesn’t support upside-down portrait mode. If your app doesn’t rotate automatically when someone holds the device in the **wrong** orientation, they’ll know instinctively to rotate it. You don’t need to tell them. **Nice, it's a USER ERROR**.